# Index-based access to rows in pandas.DataFrame with Sparse columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

Due to memory limitations I have to use sparse columns in a `pandas.DataFrame` (pandas version 1.0.5).
Unfortunately, with index-based access to rows (using `.loc[]`), I am running into the following issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1],
                             [1, 0, 0, 0],
                             [0, 1, 0, 0]])
)
```

```
df
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0
```

If using `.loc`:

```
df.loc[[0,1]]
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2       3
0   0   0   NaN     1
1   1   0   NaN     0
```

Ideally, I would be expecting `0`s for column two as well. My hypothesis of what's happening here is that the internal csc-matrix representation and the fact that I am accessing values in rows of a column that does not contain any non-zero values originally messes with the fill-value. The `dtypes` sort of speak against this:

```
df.loc[[0,1]].dtypes
```

Output:

```
0         Sparse[int32, 0]
1         Sparse[int32, 0]
2       Sparse[float64, 0]
3         Sparse[int32, 0]
```

(note that the fill-value is still given as `0`, even though the view's `dtype` for column 2 has changed from `Sparse[int32, 0]` to `Sparse[float64, 0]`).

Can anyone tell me whether all `NaN`s occuring in a row-sliced `pd.DataFrame` with sparse columns indeed refer to the respective zero-value and will not "hide" any actual non-zero entries? Is there a "safe" way to use index-based row access on `pd.DataFrame`s with sparse columns?

Comment: Interesting... `df.loc[0:1]`   Try this.

Comment: yeah, that does it (even though my usecase will require concrete index values). i have never looked into details of the `.loc` implementation, but it seems a bit odd that a slice would work but a concrete index (the issue above occurs also with `pd.Index([0, 1])`) doesn't. do you maybe have any ideas why this could be the case?

Comment: not sure, but my guess is that `.loc[[0, 1]]` is accessing each index and returning a concatenation (thus not having data in col 2), while `.loc[0:1]` or generally `.loc[0:1, :]` seems to build the index and column slices and then looking for the data (thus having all idxs/cols in slice and rebuilding the sparse matrix) ...  a workaround would be `df.loc[[0, 1]].fillna().astype(np.int32)`, have you looked into a smaller datatype? say `np.int8` or `np.bool_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this indeed turned out to be a bug in `pandas` that has been fixed in version 1.1.0 (see [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29563) for an issue description and the [changelog for 1.1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#notable-bug-fixes)).

In 1.1.0 the minimal example works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1],
                             [1, 0, 0, 0],
                             [0, 1, 0, 0]])
)
df.loc[[0, 1]]
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   0
```